# Cloned content editable div not retaining keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to Jquery and looking to solve the reason a keydown event on a content editable div isn't cloning. I thought I had solved things when I discovered clone(true), but no my code still isn't working. The code below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically I'm attaching a keydown event to a content editable div then cloning it. However the cloned div isn't working like the original div.

I've been searching for a solution for a good while now and was hope someone could give me an answer so I can move on - many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>untitled</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

    var mymax1 = 10;

    $('#List_1').keydown(function(e){ check_charcount(mymax1, e); });

    function check_charcount(mymax1, e)
    {   
        <!--prevent line breaks, that is the enter key from working-->
        if(e.keyCode==13){
        e.preventDefault();
        }

        if(e.which != 8 && $('#List_1').text().length > mymax1{
            $("#List_1").css("background-color","yellow"); 

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    <!---->
    var $cloned = $('#hope').clone(true);

    $('#placeHere').append($cloned.html());
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="hope">
<div id="List_1"  contentEditable="true">TEXT</div>
</div>

</br>
<div id="placeHere"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery documentation for [**clone()**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it has the following note in it: `Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things were not correct in your code as pointed **Ian**.
In your keydown function you are using `$('list_1')`, you should use reference to element.
BTW, clone keep id attr which mean that your cloned element get same id as original, which is not valid. See working code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var mymax1 = 10;

    $('#List_1').keydown(function (e) {
        check_charcount(mymax1, e);
    });

    function check_charcount(mymax, e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (e.which != 8 && $(e.target).text().length > mymax) {
            $(e.target).css("background-color", "yellow");

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }


    var $cloned = $('#hope').clone(true);

    $('#placeHere').append($cloned.contents().removeAttr('id'));
});
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MJEeu/)

Comment: Thought I would just say that I changed id="List_1" to class="List_1" so that I can add more divs (they're going to be dynamic). I also removed .removeAttr('id') and things seem to work fine. Need to try it on the full version now. Thanks again.

Comment: Browser will not complain about duplicate id. Problem will come when you will try to access element using id selector. For example, with multiple #List_1 elements, using $('#List_1'), only first matched element will be selected.